# Script to generate broken links report for entire branches

Tags: broken-links

We have just updated our company wide website to a new platform, but have come away with a very large amount of broken links. Currently the site is available in multiple languages, each divided into sub-branches & workareas to cover different product offerings. What would be the best way to write a script to auto-generate a list or report of all broken links within a specific workarea?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write any scripts.

There are already a gazillion of applications (Gui, Console or Web) that do what you want.

Here is an [example freeware application](http://www.control-f.com/FreeLinkChecker/).